# Issue in launching spyder that was installed using pip install on Python 3.6.1

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd

I have windows-7 64 bit machine and Python3.6.1(32-bit) installed on it. I wanted to try spyder as IDE for python. I don't have Anaconda or anything like that. So, I installed spyder from command line (cmd.exe) and it did install successfully and prompt returned.

I think it is installed because

1. I can see spyder3.exe under C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
2. From cmd.exe when I enter spyder3 it doesn't throw any error and a rotating circle appears which indicates something is processing. But nothing is launched.
3. After running spyder3 from cmd.exe though nothing gets launched except the rotating circle for couple of seconds, I see spyder.lock folder under C:\Users\UserName\.spyder-py3
4. When I delete spyder.lock folder under C:\Users\UserName\.spyder-py3 and run spyder3 again in cmd.exe the folder is created again.

**Question:** How can I make spyder launch? Did I do something wrong while installing spyder or am I trying to launch it with an incorrect method?

Comment: Do not hide parent console window (Windows)? `spyder3 --show-console`

Comment: Hi JosefZ. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this command from cmd.exe and it accepts it as a valid command and shows spinning circle for few seconds but nothing is launched. I tried running this command and then spyder3 but still same result. Spinning circle for few seconds and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to install PyQt5. It is a requirement for spyder on windows and I was missing it. After I installed it I can launch spyder3 from cmd.exe